# python find permutation mapping

Tags: python, permutation

I want to find the mapping given two arrays A and B, which are permutations of each other. An equivalent function would be

```
import numpy as np
def perm_map(A, B):
    return [np.where(np.array(B) == el)[0][0] for el in A]

print( perm_map(['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'C', 'A']) )
```

result for this example is [2, 0, 1]

Questions:

- Am I calling it correctly?
- Is there a built-in efficient function for this?

Comment: The answers on the above link provide this exact same result without the need for a list comprehension or loops of any sort. It's quicker too : )

Comment: In my opinion the best answer in above link is by hermidalc. I have also tested a popular answer by RomanS and it does not work